# Андроид: String[] в int[]

Tags: android, массивы

Прошу помощи в решении следующего вопроса:

Имеется строковый массив, содержащий в себе список путей к изображениям, а именно

```
private String[] stringArray = new String[]{"R.mipmap.img1", "R.mipmap.img2", "R.mipmap.img3"};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привести данный массив к виду:

```
private int[] intArray = new int[]{R.mipmap.img1, R.mipmap.img2, R.mipmap.img3};
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Для того чтобы прокастить строку в число, строка должна, как минимум, содержать валидные литералы для числа;)

Comment: @JavaJunior, в данном случае это не обязательно. Т.к. эти строки это указатели на картинки в ресурсах, то средствами Android-SDK их таки можно превратить в значения констант из класса `R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из способов:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"R.mipmap.img1", "R.mipmap.img2", "R.mipmap.img3"};
int length = stringArray.length;
int[] intArray = new int[length];
for(int i = 0; i<length; ++i){
  String[] names = stringArray[i].split("\\.");
  intArray[i] = context.getResources().getIdentifier(names[2], names[1], context.getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает, как нужно.